# replacing Fragment with a listener within this Fragment and a method in the Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, static-methods

I have a Fragment with a Button embedded inside of a FragmentActivity. When I click the button I want the Fragment to be replaced with another Fragment. The problem is: the Fragment is a inner static class of my Activity and the method is a non-static one. I solved this problem by making an instance of my Activity class, but when I click on the button inside the fragment the application crashes.

Here is the code:

```
public class Stdp extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

public static class Bottomfrag extends SherlockFragment {

    static Bottomfrag newInstance() {
        Bottomfrag f = new Bottomfrag();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_choose, container, false);
        View li = v.findViewById(R.id.layoutbottom);
        li.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBB33"));
        View button = v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Stdp t = new Stdp();
                t.addFragmentToStack();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stdp);

    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.test_array, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment bottom = new Bottomfrag();
        ft.add(R.id.su1, bottom);
        ft.commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void addFragmentToStack() {
Fragment newFragment = Bottomfrag.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.su1, newFragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
}
```

---

I found a solution for my problem. The only thing I had to do is to move the addFragmentToStack to the Bottomfrag class.

Comment: Whats the logcat output... what's the error message?

Comment: If your code still has `Stdp t = new Stdp();` then you definitely have ***not*** found a solution to your problem. Just saying...

Comment: No, I removed that instance. I found this solution on Google while searching on how to refer a non-static method in a static one. 
I totally agree with your post below that it is useless in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I solved this problem by making an instance of my Activity class.

Instantiating an `Activity` is almost never a solution when it comes to Android development... in fact, I can't imagine a scenario in which you would ever want to create a new `Activity` using the default constructor.

You can reference the static instance of your `Activity` with `ActivityName.this`.

You should also move `addFragmentToStack` to the `Bottomfrag` class.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I found a solution for my problem. The only thing I had to do is to move the addFragmentToStack to the Bottomfrag class.

Comment: Nice to hear. You should add your solution as a new answer and then accept it by clicking the check mark. :) http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: I can't post my answer because I have less than 10 reputation. I have to wait for 8 hours :D

Comment: @user1538698 ok, well I added it to my answer if you don't want to bother adding your own... it'll get you an extra 2 points either way lol